# haproxy session stats change suddenly

Tags: haproxy, stunnel

We have a load balancer where if we refresh the stats page over and over, we will notice that the Current sessions value will stay stable for a time, say 45-50 sessions per server more or less, then suddenly we will refresh the page and one server will have 0 and the other server will have 2. Then, on the next reload of the stats page, we're right back to 45-50. We will be refreshing the page every 1-2 seconds

My question is, what would cause the stats module to suddenly show that there are only two sessions open, then go right back to the normal session count within a one to two second period?

**Edit:**
I've also found that all stats look like they reset during this period, not just current sessions.  For instance, here's a before, during and after on bytes in - it  jumps down and back up too - not just current sessions... though I believe Bytes In is a long term "only grows higher " stat, not a "snapshot" stat.

```
bytes in before: 231,766,635
bytes in during: 7,704,962
bytes in after: 233,395,640
```

**Edit 2:**
Thanks Willy, looks like you are right. The comment in the config file was misleading there I have to say.

```
[admin@p2378442 ~]$ ps ax |grep hapro 
9833 pts/0 S+ 0:00 grep hapro 
18375 ? Ss 0:02 /usr/sbin/haproxy -D -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid
18376 ? Ss 0:25 /usr/sbin/haproxy -D -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are running with more than one process and the stats you're seeing are the one of the process that catches your stats request. One more reason never to run more than one process at a time and to remove the "nbproc" line.

Comment: I've changed the config file, will restart it later tonight. Thanks for the help.